# How to fix warning: comparison between pointer and integer in C

Tags: c

So for my `C` code, I am coding a binary search tree that takes in a typedef struct called node that has char* name and char* phone. What I do in this code is that I put this in a binary search tree and output the list alphabetically with the phoneNum next to it. It works but I get the error

warning: comparison between pointer and integer

What would I do to fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#define MAX 10

char* nameArray[] = {"George", "Zoey", "Hannah", "David", "Avery",
        "Justin", "Sasha", "Babara", "Steve", "Garnett", NULL};
char* number[] = {"610-11-1212", "508-123-1000", "617-555-1212",
        "818-919-8100", "710-777-1170", "310-333-1300", "510-555-1001","333-310-3201", "445-440-0044", "220-210-2210", NULL};
int flag;
typedef struct node
{

    char* name;
    char* phoneNum;
    struct node * left;
    struct node * right;
} node_t;


//int compareStrings(char* str1, char* str2){return (strcmp(str1, str2));}


void insert(node_t * tree, char* name, char* phoneNum);
void print_tree_inorder(node_t * current);
s
int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    node_t * test_list = malloc(sizeof(node_t));

    /* set values explicitly, alternative would be calloc() */
    test_list->name =  "";
    test_list->phoneNum = "";
    test_list->left = NULL;
    test_list->right = NULL;


         for(int i = 0; i<MAX; i++){
            insert(test_list,nameArray[i],number[i] );
        }

    printf("\n In order\n");
    print_tree_inorder(test_list);
}

void insert(node_t * tree, char* name, char* phoneNum)
{  

    if (tree->name == 0)
    {
        /* insert on current (empty) position */
        tree->name = name;
        tree->phoneNum = phoneNum;
    }
    else
    {

        if ( strcmp(tree->name, name) < tree->name) //here
        {
            /* insert left */
            if (tree->left != NULL)
            {
                insert(tree->left, name, phoneNum);
            }
            else /* no left nodes*/
            {
                tree->left = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
                /* set values explicitly, alternative would be calloc() */
                tree->left->name = name;
                tree->left->phoneNum = phoneNum;
                tree->left->left = NULL;
                tree->left->right = NULL;
            }
        }
        else /*add node to right */
        {
            if ( strcmp(tree->name, name) >= tree->name) //here
            {
                /* insert right */
                if (tree->right != NULL)
                {
                    insert(tree->right, name, phoneNum);
                }
                else
                {
                    tree->right = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
                    /* set values explicitly, alternative would be calloc() */
                    tree->right->name = name;
                    tree->right->phoneNum = phoneNum;
                    tree->right->left = NULL;
                    tree->right->right = NULL;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

void print_tree_inorder(node_t * current) {
    if (current == NULL) return;
    print_tree_inorder(current->left);
    printf(" %s  %s\n", current->name, current->phoneNum);
    print_tree_inorder(current->right);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And don't forget to add a comment in the code you show to tell us *where* it is.

Comment: A hint though: [Read more about the `strcmp` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp), especially what it *returns*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html:

> The strcmp() function compares the two strings s1 and s2.  It returns
>   an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if s1 is found,
>   respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2.

So you should compare the result of strcmp with 0, not with a string.

Comment: Thank you! This really helped me. I am new to using strcmp() and I am also new to C.

Answer (score 1):

from [strcmp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html)

```
RETURN VALUE
       The strcmp() and strncmp() functions return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if s1 (or the first
       n bytes thereof) is found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2.
```

your comparison,  `( strcmp(tree->name, name) < tree->name)` , is a comparing `char *` with `int` which is actually wrong

in general using `strcmp` while comparing strings `s1`, `s2` can be evaluated as simple as

```
if( strcmp(s1,s2) == 0 ) 
{
   // equal
}
else if( strcmp(s1,s2) == 0 ) 
{
   // s1 < s2
}
else 
{
  // s1 > s2
}
```